# How to add a button to context in react

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to store a button element globally using react context

```
const QuitLesson = ({goToLessons}) => {

  // this is where I'm trying to create a new context
  const closeBtnContext = React.createContext();

  return (
    <div>
      <div styleName='close'>
        <button
          id='closeLessonBtn'
          type='button'
          styleName='closeIcon'
          onClick={() => setQuitOverlayOpen(true)}
          disabled={quitOverlayOpen}>
          <img src='/resources/img/btn_close.svg'/>
        </button>
      </div>
      {quitOverlayOpen &&
        <Overlay
          onClose={() => setQuitOverlayOpen(false)}
          onConfirm={goToLessons}
        />
      }
    </div>
  );
};

QuitLesson.propTypes = {
  goToLessons: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default CSSModules(QuitLesson, styles);
```

How do I add this button to context so I can use it in another component later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't createContext inside a functional component.

```
 // Declair this outside of the QuitLesson functional component.
const closeBtnContext = React.createContext();

const QuitLesson = ({goToLessons}) => {

  return (
    <div>
      <div styleName='close'>
        <button
          id='closeLessonBtn'
          type='button'
          styleName='closeIcon'
          onClick={() => setQuitOverlayOpen(true)}
          disabled={quitOverlayOpen}>
          <img src='/resources/img/btn_close.svg'/>
        </button>
      </div>
      {quitOverlayOpen &&
        <Overlay
          onClose={() => setQuitOverlayOpen(false)}
          onConfirm={goToLessons}
        />
      }
    </div>
  );
};

QuitLesson.propTypes = {
  goToLessons: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default CSSModules(QuitLesson, styles);
```

I also think you maybe trying to use context in a way that it wasn't intended. the context is for passing data (state) and functions primarily to update that state. 
from https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

> Context is designed to share data that can be considered “global” for
>   a tree of React components, such as the current authenticated user,
>   theme, or preferred language.

It sounds like you want to store the actual component in state to then reuse later. A better way of doing this that is 'React' friendly would be to create the closeBtnContext.context and wrap the app in the closeBtnContext.provider and then wrap the QuitLesson component with the closeBtnContext.consumer and then import the QuitLesson component wherever it is needed in your app.